# Get last written files without time using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a folder with 198 files, among them there are 25 files with last writing date of 06.22.2014. I'm trying to get this set of last modified files, using the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetLatestFiles(string path)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .GetFiles("*.log")
            .GroupBy(f => f.Extension)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime
            .Date
            .ToShortDateString())
            .First());
}
```

However, it returns me only one file, because it checks also last time modification, despite I crop the date. Is there any approach to enumerate this list of files excluding time?

Comment: Just take `First()` out.

Comment: Y r u using `First()` ?

Comment: Why do you use `GroupBy ... Extension` if you already filtered out all but `*.log` files?

Comment: Indeed, this is all kinds of messed up. Are you really trying to get all the log files which share the most recent last-modified date?

Comment: if I take `First()` out, it starts complaining me to the incorrect type casting. If the end of my code looks like `.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date.ToShortDateString())) as IEnumerable<FileInfo>;`, it returns me null :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, I'm trying to get all logs with the most recent last-modified date. Without time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to tell what you're doing if you don't just align on dots, but on top-level calls:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetLatestFiles(string path)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .GetFiles("*.log")
            .GroupBy(f => f.Extension)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime
                                                   .Date
                                                   .ToShortDateString())
                          .First());
}
```

Now it's more obvious that you're doing a *string-based* ordering. Unless you happen to be in a culture which puts the year first, then the month, then the day, that's almost certainly not what you want. You probably don't care about the string representation at all. **Always avoid converting to a string unless you're really interested in a textual representation.**

Next, you're doing a couple of odd things:

- You're only fetching the "*.log" files, but you're grouping by extension
- You're only taking the most first result of each group after ordering

I suspect you really want to group by *date*, and return everything in the most recent group. For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetLatestFiles(string path)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .GetFiles("*.log")
            .GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key) // Order the groups by date (desc)
            .First(); // Just return the most recent group
}
```

(Note that this will fail if there are no files in the directory... what do you want it to do in this case?)

You should also consider what time zone you're interested in - two files may have the same last-modified date in one time zone, but not in another...

Comment: That's what I really wanted! Many thanks. The rest part of problems like empty folder or time-zone is already managet :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `First()` at the end is reasonable that you get only one file. If You remove it you will have all the files ordered as you have already done.

However using the query you have alread built, you will not take that you want. Instead of this, you could try something like the following:

```
 DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.log")
                    .Where(x=>x.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()=="06/22/2014");
```

Comment: if I take `First()` out, it starts complaining me to the incorrect type casting. If the end of my code looks like `.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime.Date.ToShortDateString())) as IEnumerable<FileInfo>;`, it returns me null.

Comment: @TrevorPhilips please try the code that I have posted. As I understand the code you have and that you want to get are not consistent. Please let me know about your try. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to take off the `First()` :

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetLatestFiles(string path)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .GetFiles("*.log")
            .GroupBy(f => f.Extension)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime
            .Date
            .ToShortDateString()));
}
```